# Jquery loading different content, and manipulate the loaded content with the still running js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Well I have 3 files. 1 is php.index 2 is javascript and 3 is php.loadinternet

php.index has a small form

```
<div id="login-button" class = "knopf"><a href="?view=logs">Log in</a></div>
```

which is being manipulated with

```
$("#login-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = $("#connectwindow, value").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/loadinternet.php",
        data: {"targetip": input},
        success: function(data){
            //history.pushState({"internet.php?view=internetlog");
            $('#logoutput').html(data);


        },
        error: function(){
            alert ("error loading");
        }

    });
```

after the passing of the data to loadinternet it echoes back this form:

```
echo    '<div id="loginbox" align="right" class="boxgrid">
                    <form action="" method="post">Username: 
                    <input id="userlogin" type="text" class="textfieldcss" 
                    style="width: 60%;" name="username" value="'.$username.'"><br>
                    Password: &nbsp;<input id="userpassword"type="password" 
                    class="textfieldcss" style="width: 60%;" name="password" value="'.$username.'">
                    <input id="logintoip" type="submit" class="textfieldcss" style="text-align: right;" 
                    value="Log in">
                    </form>
                    </div>';
```

and the last form should be manipulated with this form: However It's not working and i've been at it for an hour now trying to wrap my head around it.. tried both with the .click() and .submit() prevention, both is not working, nor is a simple alert in that click function below

```
$("#logintoip").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = $("#userlogin, value").val();
        alert("stop");

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax/connect.php",
            data: {"targetip": input},
            success: function(index){
            $('#logoutput').html(index);
            },
            error: function(){alert("something went wrong here");}
            }       
        );

    });
```

Comment: Add a `return false;` to your click handler. Other than that: "it's not working" is too vague; what do you expect, and what happens?

Comment: i want the submit action prevented when clicking on the submit button. what actually happens, it gets submitted and the click function added on the id doesnt fire off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your page is loaded, `#logintoip` doesnt exist so the listener cannot be applied.

Try this way :

```
$(document).on('click', '#logintoip', function(e){
    (...)
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you have no javascript errors ? you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/) to check javascript errors. Moreover, `$("#userlogin, value").val();` should be write this way `$("#userlogin").val();` I think. Same for `$("#connectwindow").val();`

Comment: everything worked perfectly fine, data was being transfered from one point to another the assigned values were all valid, the valid values got sent back to the initial form, up to the point where i wanted to add another click function aka the nightmare #logintoip

Comment: Hum, when you changed your code from `$("#logintoip").click(function(e){` to `$(document).on('click', '#logintoip', function(e){`, did you purge your cache ? Use `CTRL + R`, maybe its why you didnt see the difference. Your browser may have kept the old version.

Comment: and yeah firebug doesnt fire off any errors, the problem here is the form is being submitted with the created submit button in load internet instead of listening for a click event